# border-radius tabs looks like Thunderbird tabs

Tags: html, css

Does anybody know how are developed thunderbird mail tabs (version 15)?  Look great and I'm  not really able to do the same in my app. 
Check this screen shoot: http://s7.postimage.org/ocvxg9ooq/thunder.jpg

Comment: For complicated shapes, css borders are not enough. Use images, and carefully align them to match at the borders.

Comment: You can't have those bottom borders that go outside the box with CSS, unless you use an image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I've done something like this before - check it out http://dabblet.com/gist/3166401 (great looking in IE9 as well)

And I've done now a quick version with multiple tabs: http://dabblet.com/gist/3608293/ (CSS only)

HTML:

```
<div id='tabs' class='tabs'>
    <input type='radio' name='tab' id='tab1' checked>
    <label for='tab1'><h5>Inbox</h5></label>
    <section id='inbox'>
        <h6>You have <a href='#'>1 new message</a></h6>
        <a href='#'>See all messages</a>
    </section>
    <input type='radio' name='tab' id='tab2'>
    <label for='tab2'><h5>Add-ons Manager</h5></label>
    <section id='addons'>
        <h6>Add-ons list</h6>
        <ul>
            <li>bammm bammm
        </ul>
    </section>
    <input type='radio' name='tab' id='tab3'>
    <label for='tab3'><h5>Calendar</h5></label>
    <section id='addons'>
        <h6>Scheduled</h6>
        <ul>
            <li>Tuesday, September the 4th...
        </ul>
    </section>
    <input type='radio' name='tab' id='tab4'>
    <label for='tab4'><h5>Chat</h5></label>
    <section id='addons'>
        <h6>Something here as well</h6>
        <div>something more</div>
    </section>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html { font: 90% Helvetica, sans-serif; }
.tabs {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    height: 26.5em;
    margin: 7em 0 0;
}
.tabs input[type=radio] { display: none; }
.tabs label, .tabs section { position: absolute; }
.tabs label {
    z-index: 2;
    top: 0; left: 1.5em;
    width: 9em;
    height: 2em;
    background: plum;
    background: linear-gradient(lightcyan, plum);
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.tabs h5 {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    height: 2em;
    font: 1em/2 Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 lemonchiffon;
}
.tabs label:nth-of-type(2) { left: 12em; }
.tabs label:nth-of-type(3) { left: 22.5em; }
.tabs label:nth-of-type(4) { left: 33em; }
.tabs label:before, .tabs label:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0;
    width: 1em;
    background: plum;
    background: linear-gradient(lightcyan, plum);
    content: '';
}
.tabs label:before {
    left: -.65em;
    border-radius: .4em 0 0 0;
    transform: skewX(-15deg);
}
.tabs label:after {
    right: -.65em;
    border-radius: 0 .4em 0 0;
    transform: skewX(15deg);
}
.tabs h5:before, .tabs h5:after {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -1px;
    height: .65em;
    width: .65em;
    content: '';
}
.tabs h5:before {
    left: -1.4em;
    transform: skewX(-15deg);
    background: radial-gradient(top left, 
                transparent 70.71%, plum 70.71%);
}
.tabs h5:after {
    right: -1.4em;
    transform: skewX(15deg);
    background: radial-gradient(top right, 
                transparent 70.71%, plum 70.71%);
}
.tabs section {
    display: none;
    z-index: 6;
    padding: 1em;
    border-top: solid 1px whitesmoke;
    margin-top: -1px;
    top: 2em; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(whitesmoke, gainsboro)
}
.tabs input[type=radio]:checked + label,
.tabs input[type=radio]:checked + label:before, 
.tabs input[type=radio]:checked + label:after {
    z-index: 5;
    background: whitesmoke;
    background: linear-gradient(gainsboro, whitesmoke);
}

.tabs input[type=radio]:checked + label:before, 
.tabs input[type=radio]:checked + label:after {
    background-position: 0 -1px;
}
.tabs input[type=radio]:checked + label h5:before {
    background: radial-gradient(top left, 
                transparent 70.71%, whitesmoke 70.71%);
} 
.tabs input[type=radio]:checked + label h5:after {
    background: radial-gradient(top right, 
                transparent 70.71%, whitesmoke 70.71%);
}
.tabs input[type=radio]:checked + label + section { display: block; }
```

Comment: Also in Opera, IE and Safari. Firefox is the only one that has a problem with it - I'll look into that (I actually only tested in Chrome and IE when I made it).

Comment: OK, it was because I was using `skew` (which was deprecated and doesn't work in FF starting with FF14) instead of `skewX` - test it in FF now http://dabblet.com/gist/3166401/eefdd300a2ed907ff82c189d625ef55d48beeff7

Comment: WOW thank's Ana, what about IE8 .. in IE9 it works perfect but on IE8 I don't get that shapes :| I saw is used a radial gradient for shapes and radial gradient works even in IE8.

Comment: CSS gradients don't even work in IE9. I've used filter gradients for IE (+ extra elements because filters don't work on pseudo-elements). For IE8, you have the angled lateral edges & the gradient bg, but no rounded corners. The only way you could get those in IE8 would be to use either images or perhaps a polyfill. I have never actually done that, I just let it with no rounded corners for IE8. Trying to get rounded corners for IE8 would mean writing more code, feeding more code to the older and slower browser and people don't notice missing rounded corners, but they notice slow loading pages.

Comment: I'm using pie.js a library that allows me to have css3 on IE6-8, I will try to combine them somehow :) Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

it can be done with css `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements. Take a look at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agriboz/F3UJF/) example

**Html**

```
<ul class="tabrow">
    <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
    <li class="selected"><a href="#">Sit amet</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Consectetur adipisicing</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Css**​

```
.tabrow {
        text-align: center;
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0 20px;
        padding: 0;
        line-height: 24px;
        height: 26px;
        overflow: hidden;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-family: verdana;
        position: relative;
    }
    .tabrow li {
        border: 1px solid #AAA;
        background: #D1D1D1;
        background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ECECEC 50%, #D1D1D1 100%);
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ECECEC 50%, #D1D1D1 100%);
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ECECEC 50%, #D1D1D1 100%);
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ECECEC 50%, #D1D1D1 100%);
        background: linear-gradient(top, #ECECEC 50%, #D1D1D1 100%);
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 0;
        border-top-left-radius: 6px;
        border-top-right-radius: 6px;
        box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), inset 0 1px 0 #FFF;
        text-shadow: 0 1px #FFF;
        margin: 0 -5px;
        padding: 0 20px;
    }
    .tabrow a {
          color: #555;
          text-decoration: none;
    }
    .tabrow li.selected {
        background: #FFF;
        color: #333;
        z-index: 2;
        border-bottom-color: #FFF;
    }
    .tabrow:before {
        position: absolute;
        content: " ";
        width: 100%;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #AAA;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    .tabrow li:before,
    .tabrow li:after {
        border: 1px solid #AAA;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: -1px;
        width: 5px;
        height: 5px;
        content: " ";
    }
    .tabrow li:before {
        left: -6px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
        border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 0 #D1D1D1;
    }
    .tabrow li:after {
        right: -6px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
        border-width: 0 0 1px 1px;
        box-shadow: -2px 2px 0 #D1D1D1;
    }
    .tabrow li.selected:before {
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 0 #FFF;
    }
    .tabrow li.selected:after {
        box-shadow: -2px 2px 0 #FFF;
    }​
```

**jQuery**

```
$("li").click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $("li").removeClass("selected");
     $(this).addClass("selected");
});​
```

For more details about it, you'd better to visit [here](http://css-tricks.com/better-tabs-with-round-out-borders/)